# using a IF type statement in a linq to entities SELECT NEW clause C#

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I am returning data from 2 tables, one with stop information and another with delivery information.  There can be a stop with no delivery, or with multiple deliveries.

I am returning to a datagrid and I am wanting a column showing if the record is a stop or a stop with delivery.

If the record does not have a delivery (is null) my current query returns a '0' in the deliveryID field.

I am wanting to add another field called rowType where if the deliveryID = 0 it returns a value of "Stop Only" and if anything else it returns "Stop with Delivery"
The below code works correctly but without the new field.

```
  var combinedEvents = (from d in dbContext.stop_details
                              join s in dbContext.stop_event on d.id equals s.stop_id into Inners
                              from sd in Inners.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              where (d.ship_date >= startDate && d.ship_date <= endDate)
                              select new
                              {
                                  deliveryID = (int?)sd.id ?? 0,
                                  stopID = d.id,
                                  d.ship_date,
                                  d.cust_ref_1_BOL,
                                  d.cust_ref_2_OrderNum,
                                  sd.received_by
                                  }).ToList();
```

Can I do this someway?

Comment: something like `rowType = ((int?)sd.id).HasValue ? "Stop With Delivery" : "Stop Only"` maybe?

Comment: I kept trying to do exactly that, but forgot to cast the (int?) so my HasValue would not show up.  Thanks Mate...if you wanna write it up as the answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the conditional `?` operator and duplicate your logic for `deliveryID`:

`rowType = ((int?)sd.id).HasValue ? "Stop With Delivery" : "Stop Only"`